# How to apply padding for selected item in dropdown

Tags: flutter

From below code i able to add padding to hint(placeholder), but i'm not able to add padding for selected drop Down item

```
 DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: 'Sort By,
          ),
          items: getDropDownMenuItems(["Name", "Class"]),
          value: myActivity,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),elevation: 10,
          onChanged: (String value) => {
            setState(() {
              myActivity = value;
            }),
            sortList(value)
          }),
    );


  getDropDownMenuItems(options) {
    var items = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>();
    for (String option in options) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(value: option, child: Text(option)));
    }
    return items;
  }
```

I want left side padding for selected drop down item[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Padding for the child of your dropdown

```
getDropDownMenuItems(options) {
    var items = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>();
    for (String option in options) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(value: option, child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Text(option),
);));
    }
    return items;
  }
```